# Titanium Appcelerator - fireEvent to the Webview

Tags: events, webview, titanium

Is there any possible way to fire event to the Webview before he is loaded,
and change some of his parameters?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Before it is loaded you can just add parameters, no need for an event

Comment: Actually,I'm trying to send some parameters to the Webview before it is loaded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webview.addEventListener('beforeload', function() {
    webview.evalJS('var foo='my data;');
});
```